# VoiceOver: aria-describedby / aria-labelledby is not working on svg-path

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers, wcag

I'm trying to announce the meaning of each donutchart(svg) arc/section when tab on it by using `aria-describedby` / `aria-labelledby`.

- Added `id` to `div` which is the content needs to be announced.
- Added `aria-describedby` / `aria-labelledby` with the same string as id to `svg path`.
- Added `tabindex = "0"` to `svg path`.

Tested on the MacOS VoiceOver with Chrome/Safari and iPhone ios VoiceOver with Safari.

When tab on the arc/section, the VoiceOver will only announce **graphic symbol** instead of the content of div. However, the announced content is ignored no matter using `aria-describedby` / `aria-labelledby`.

```html
<svg class="donut-chart" width="236px" viewBox="0 0 236 236">
<g class="donut-chart-arcs">
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M118,218.3
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 117.50623649597293, 218.29878462674455
    L117.63984309118025,191.15911349244897
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 118, 191.16 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#0046ad" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="0.28"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M117.50623649597293,218.29878462674455
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 33.32260328573676, 171.757124976093
    L56.23531063194917,157.21107939432665
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 117.63984309118025, 191.15911349244897 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#ec0439" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="56.89"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M33.32260328573676,171.757124976093
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 63.65981518807381, 33.695585438212646
    L78.36362990188914,56.5073682019904
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 56.23531063194917, 157.21107939432665 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#1977d3" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="88.95"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M63.65981518807381,33.695585438212646
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 173.18230621846504, 34.244384782800665
    L158.25062335935098,56.907668900395784
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 78.36362990188914, 56.5073682019904 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#7300cd" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="65.7"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M173.18230621846504,34.244384782800665
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 117.99999999999994, 218.3
    L117.99999999999996,191.16
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 158.25062335935098, 56.907668900395784 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#aa00aa" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="145.55"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

```
<div id="0.28">$0.28</div>
<div id="56.89">$56.89</div>
<div id="88.95">$88.95</div>
<div id="65.7">$65.7</div>
<div id="145.55">$145.55</div>
```

announce the content in `div`

Answer (score 2):

I’m not able to test in VoiceOver, but I’ll provide an answer based on the standards.

### You *must* name focusable elements

If you allow focus on these elements, they *must* have an accessible name, provided by `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`.

A description is only optionally read by screen readers, which is a configuration choice. You might provide one additionally, but not as the only text.

### You *must not* name path elements without a role

The [ARIA standard forbids to name elements with certain roles](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#namefromprohibited).

It‘s unclear which role a SVG `path` element has implicitly, since there is no *ARIA in SVG* standard. It might have `role="none"` which is a synonym for the `presentation` role, which in turn *must not be named*. This is the case in Firefox.

### Which role to use for your `path`?

So the question follows which role should you use.

The standard to refer to here would be the W3C Recommendation [WAI-ARIA Graphics Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0).

So it seems that Safari might take its interpretation from this recommendation, when announcing *graphic symbol*. The standard says:

> A graphical object used to convey a simple meaning or category, where the meaning is more important than the particular visual appearance. It may be **a component of a larger structured graphic such as a chart** or map.

(Emphasis mine)

The [SVG–Aria Element Mapping Table](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/#mapping_role_table) also maps `<path>` to `graphics-symbol` if it [should be included in the accessibility tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/#include_elements).

Reasons to include the element are `aria-label` and `tabindex` attributes.

In the W3C Wiki there also is an older page called [SVG Accessibility/ARIA roles for charts](https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Accessibility/ARIA_roles_for_charts). The corresponding role for your chart would probably be `graphics dataunit`:

> A distinct data value in a chart or map.

Since the Wiki page never made it to a Recommendation, you *could* follow the standard’s suggestion to provide a `aria-roledescription` to approach the wiki role:

```
<path role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="dataunit">
```

If you check out [Highcharts’ Donut chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut), you might notice that they use `<path role="img" aria-label="…">`.

### Focus or not?

It’s unclear whether or not you should make these data units focusable. It might be preferable to not navigate within simple charts, doing so in more complex charts most probably improves comprehension of the data groups.

You should test with screen reader users.

In general, only interactive elements that can be clicked, should be focusable. Or put the other way around:

> Focusable elements should have interactive semantics

If elements are focusable, [focus needs to be visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html), so you’ll need to add a `:focus` style as well.

If you have bigger charts than that one, it would be better to provide a single tab stop, as explained in [Keyboard Navigation Inside Components](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-keyboard-navigation-inside-components).

Arrow keys then allow to focus single data units.

Again, [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) provide a good example for this.

### Watch out for . in IDs

It’s not a good practice to use periods `.` in IDs, as [MDN warns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id#sect2):

> `.` has a special meaning in CSS (it acts as a class selector). Unless you are careful to escape it in the CSS, it won't be recognized as part of the value of an id attribute. It is easy to forget to do this, resulting in bugs in your code that could be hard to detect.

### Playground

```html
<svg class="donut-chart" width="236px" viewBox="0 0 236 236">
<g class="donut-chart-arcs">
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M118,218.3
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 117.50623649597293, 218.29878462674455
    L117.63984309118025,191.15911349244897
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 118, 191.16 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#0046ad" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="0-28" role="img"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M117.50623649597293,218.29878462674455
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 33.32260328573676, 171.757124976093
    L56.23531063194917,157.21107939432665
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 117.63984309118025, 191.15911349244897 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#ec0439" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="56-89" role="graphics-symbol" aria-roledescription="dataunit"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M33.32260328573676,171.757124976093
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 63.65981518807381, 33.695585438212646
    L78.36362990188914,56.5073682019904
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 56.23531063194917, 157.21107939432665 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#1977d3" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="88.95"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M63.65981518807381,33.695585438212646
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 173.18230621846504, 34.244384782800665
    L158.25062335935098,56.907668900395784
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 78.36362990188914, 56.5073682019904 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#7300cd" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="65.7"></path>
<path class="donut-chart-path" d="M173.18230621846504,34.244384782800665
    A100.3, 100.3 0 0 1 117.99999999999994, 218.3
    L117.99999999999996,191.16
    A73.16, 73.16 0 0 0 158.25062335935098, 56.907668900395784 z" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2px" fill="#aa00aa" opacity="1" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="145.55"></path>
</g>
</svg>

<div id="0-28">$0.28</div>
<div id="56-89">$56.89</div>
<div id="88-95">$88.95</div>
<div id="65-7">$65.7</div>
<div id="145-55">$145.55</div>
```

Comment: Note that it's only useful to make each element focusable only if you can actually interact with those elements. Also, aria-label is probably better than aria-labelledby here, so you can avoid to have values read twice.

Comment: Thanks I know that charts are a huge topic. I’m wondering what you think of Highcharts’ keyboard navigation. Wouldn’t you agree that navigating [a line chart like this one](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative#highcharts-zz3s5wf-0) with several data lines is easy to navigate with arrow keys? What are the alternatives if you leave the screen reader in browse mode? Would you prefer a data table as an alternative to the chart?

Comment: I much more prefer a traditional table in that kind of situation, but that's a personal opinion of someone relatively used to math, numbers and stats. For those who are afraid of tables, their solution is excellent as well including the keyboard navigation. It's working quite well when staying in browse mode without using their keyboard navigation as well. That's probably one of the most accessible automatically generated charts I saw so far.

Comment: Hmm, that w3 document is not canonical. I am very curious about its providence! It was last updated in 2015. Some good stuff there (like graphics-legend). But only three roles from graphics ARIA have "made it" in the real world. They are "graphics-document" (a container for a view), "graphics-object" (a nestable, meaningful thing) and "graphics-symbol" (a 'leaf' in the tree). More info https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0/

Comment: Ah that’s the document I was looking for. Maybe I should refer to that official one in my answer.

Comment: @brennanyoung I had tried to find relevant recommendations on the WAI site, but couldn’t find a list of standards. Would you happen to know of one?

Comment: That would be a neat data visualisation (all the specs hyperlinked, with indication of which ones are at "draft" stage, and which are "candidate recommendations" etc. Regarding graphics ARIA: AFAIK we are at aria 1.2 (with some gaps) and graphics-aria 1.0 - I've heard caveats about graphics-aria support, although I think it works ok across browsers

Comment: Yeah, that would be neat. I also found the SVG-AAM https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/ which are relevant here as well. Also, still in Draft state. (:

Comment: btw, ARIA for data has been stagnant for a few years. I'm trying to get something moving again. Join the party https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/991

Comment: Here's the roadmap https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/roadmap